# Firebase Authentication unable to enable Google auth method - "Error updating Google"

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-oauth

I am trying to enable the Firebase authentication with the Google Auth sign-in method, but enabling it and clicking "save" [shows the error "Error updating Google"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HMVGD.png).

In the Google Cloud Console activity logs, it shows:

> Failed:google.internal.firebase.v1.FirebaseInternalProductService.EnableGoogleSignIn

With the error message "Not found (HTTP 404): Operation failed with error code NOT_FOUND."

However, when I tried this in a new Google Cloud project, it worked perfectly. I have tried removing and recreating the Firebase Admin SDK, removing and creating a new app, and removing the OAuth credentials.
I cannot seem to find any solution to this problem other than creating a new project, but I would prefer to keep my existing project ID.

Alternatively, if there is any way to reset my GCP project or remake it with the same ID, that would also be fine.

Comment: Improve your Question! Could you give examples with a description of the codes, for your question? This practice will considerably improve this problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This issue is caused by deleting the OAuth client autogenerated by Firebase by default.

To solve it, you need to first create a new OAuth 2 client ID, and set the necessary redirect URIs for your Firebase app (they should default to something like `https://{PROJECT_ID}.web.app/__/auth/handler`).

Then, call [this](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.defaultSupportedIdpConfigs/patch) API - the request should look something like this, using the client ID and client secret from the credentials generated above:

`PATCH` `https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/admin/v2/projects/{PROJECT_ID}/defaultSupportedIdpConfigs/google.com`

```json
{
  "name": "projects/{PROJECT_ID}/defaultSupportedIdpConfigs/google.com",
  "enabled": true,
  "clientId": "{YOUR_CLIENT_ID}",
  "clientSecret": "{YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET}"
}
```

After making this API call, the Google authentication provider should be enabled.

Comment: How can I get the authentication headers with the required scopes to hit this API?

Comment: @Denerator You can use a service account, but the easiest way to do this if it's just a one-time thing is to use the "Try this API" on the API explorer (https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.defaultSupportedIdpConfigs/patch) and put in your request there so you don't have to authenticate yourself.

Comment: @infrxion Thanks a lot for your help. I have the same issue. Calling the identitytoolkit api as described in your answer does not work unfortunately. I get an error 404 CONFIGURATION_NOT_FOUND. Any idea how to make it work ?

Comment: ok I found the solution. I had to recreate the configuration. On the "try this API" page click on create instead of patch. parent param is "projects/<your-project-id>. then same parameters as given by @infrxion. This page was also very useful: https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/provisioning/configure-oauth

Comment: @log0 Thanks your comment helped me more than dspeyrer's answer. I think you should post your comment as a proper answer in this thread it will help a lot of future visitors.

Comment: Thanks @log0, btw, the idpId is `google.com` when calling the api from that page

Comment: Thank you @log0. Your answer saved my day. because I was going to remove firebase, google cloud, ... projects and create all of them again.

Comment: Thanks @log0. Here is the link to the api with the Create method (not Patch). I had trouble finding it, so thought the next guy might find it useful. https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.defaultSupportedIdpConfigs/create

Answer (score 0):

*Before to begin, you must have created a new oaut-credentian gcp console, because is tha main problem here.*

You nee create a new oauth provider, you can use the [next link](https://cloud.google.com/identity-platform/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.defaultSupportedIdpConfigs/create) to authenticate a try the request using data like next:

- Parent: `projects/**put here your project number**`
- idpId (identity provider): `google.com`

#### Request Body

```
{
  "name": "projects/**put here your project number**/defaultSupportedIdpConfigs/google.com",
  "enabled": true,
  "clientId": "**put here your client id**",
  "clientSecret": "**put here your client secret**"
}
```