# Firestore can't be updated manually in the console and with Js

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-console

I have a firbebase project and since today I can't edit it with code and manually in the firebase console.

Here is an image of the structure of the project: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qe1Nv.png

I use the following code to write usernames to a document in the firestore:

```
const auth = firebase.auth();
const db = firebase.firestore();
db.collection("users_information").doc("a_document").update({
     "username": "some username"
 })
```

but it throws this error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5H60.png

If I try to edit or delete the documents in the console the following error comes up:
[image]

Translation in English: **The field couldn't be saved**

Does anybody have an idea why this happens?
It could be an issue with the rules but I don't think so:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

Yes I know the rules are very weak but I am still developing. I have also heard often, that firebase sometimes diables a service if weak rules are public too long. But if that happens you receive an email and I didn't.
I hompe you can help me ^^

Edit:
I just received an email from Firebase, that there was a server issue. It wasn't my fault and it works again now.

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: _"...then say me what I should specify more"_ - I have. It's the second link.

Comment: If you cannot create a [mcve] that reproduces the problem the question is off-topic for SO

Comment: The question doesn't contain *any* information which might be used to diagnose the problem.  This will likely be closed as unanswerable.

Comment: Whenever you have a problem like this in the Firebase console, I recommend these troubleshooting steps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67204755/firebase-authentication-unable-to-enable-google-auth-method-error-updating-go/67205382#67205382

Comment: Also posted on https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/mw9jnw/i_cant_update_my_firestore_documents_manually_and/

Comment: The console is unaffected by rules. As the super to your project, when you log into the console, it's wide open. So, knowing specifically where the error is will help. That being said, there is nothing anyone here can do about errors in the Firebase Console. That's a job for Firebase Support so you should reach out to them if that's where the error is.

Comment: @Jay yeah I just took a break to eat something. I came back and magically everything works again. I think it was a server issue or so. I wasted a few hours now but I am glad it is working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue within your Firebase Project, This is what happens when either your rules are left public too long or there is a server outage. Firestore can no longer be read or written until it has been resolved.

Double-check your Firestore rules are secure and if problems persist, please contact [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support)

Comment: what do you mean with public too long? My rules allow every read or write because I am still developing.

Comment: @Andreas this is not a coding issue he can fix. it's either an outage or restriction on his firebase project. there is no code.

Comment: Allowing every read and write is leaving it public. have you been receiving emails about your firebase security rules? they typically warn you a few days prior.

Comment: No I did not receive any emails.

Comment: then it was a service outage, for rules, a simple `allow read, write: if request.auth.uid == user;` should suffice for developmental purposes - it ensures that users are at the minimum signed in as a requirement, you can modify and adjust your rules from there.